# Epub to PDF converter, Offline

Tags: pdf, document-converter, file-converter, epub, file-conversion

Almost every app I see is using cloud/server to convert epub to pdf. Is there an offline app that does the conversion locally? If not, what's the reason they do it on the server?

I'm not looking for an epub reader.

Both Android and iOS are fine.

Comment: So you are looking for a converter for mobile OS, right?

Comment: yes. . @convert

Comment: If you have access to a computer, Mac, Win, Nix, then Calibre is pretty much the 'standard'.